# Is there a way to take videos on iOS, with music playing?

Tags: iphone, ios

I came over a bug last month that enabled me to legitimately record a video on my iPhone's camera app without having to pause the music that was playing. But I shut my phone off and back on and it stopped working, I wish someone knew how to trigger this again or inform me if it was patched by apple in a recent update, but yea, that's basically it.

Comment: Why? What's the point? The sound will be crap anyway so why not just add the music after instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently record a video while playing music using the native app.

Good news is that you can use 3rd party apps to do it instead, [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/record-and-listen/id1023640638) is an example.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use the iPhone app [Mideo: Record and Listen](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mideo-video-listen-to-music/id1358135284?mt=8) and it doesn't pause my music (Spotify, Apple Music, SoundCloud, etc) when I record video. Disclaimer: I helped develop this app.

Answer (score -1):

I use Snapchat and than save the video.

Comment: The only free solution